# Summernote table with more styling

Tags: jquery, summernote

Is there any workaround to get more styling - bordered,header,stripped for the bootstrap table that summernote use ?

I have seen a form from summernote named [MaterialNote](http://www.web-forge.info/projects/materialNote) have the table that I am after.
[image]

I have figured how table classes can be passed as summernote option :

```
$('textarea').summernote({
        tableClassName: 'table table-striped '     
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you need customise your template.

please open document summernote.js

and search this code:

```
    var $table = $('<table>' + trHTML + '</table>');
```

enter your css class in this point.

```
var $table = $('<table class='teste'>' + trHTML + '</table>');
```

and edit your css file:

```
.teste
{

}
```

I hope it helped

Comment: Your answer dffinately shed some light - but this can be done without modifying the original light : $('textarea').summernote({
        tableClassName: 'table table-striped '     
    });

Comment: But my actual query is how I can - modify the table toolbar option so that I can take the options.